# how to shift first array element at last without reset array key and produce new array

Tags: php

Here is my PHP code with out :

```
<?php
$stack = array( 0 => array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry"),1 => array("banana", "apple", "raspberry"),2 => array("apple", "raspberry"),'a' => array("raspberry"));

$temp = array_keys($stack);
array_shift($temp);

foreach($temp as $item){
    $dd[$item] = $stack[$item];
}
print_r($dd);
?>
```

OUTPUT IS :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => banana
            [1] => apple
            [2] => raspberry
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => raspberry
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => raspberry
        )

)
```

But First Element is missing when loop through I print array. it should be at last in array list.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code It will shift first array and add at last of array without reset array key:

I hope this work for you...

```
<?php

$stack = array( 0 => array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry"),1 => array("banana", "apple", "raspberry"),2 => array("apple", "raspberry"),'a' => array("raspberry"));

$temp = array_keys($stack);
$tem = array_shift($temp);
$temp[] = $tem;
$dd = array();

foreach($temp as $item){
    $dd[$item] = $stack[$item];
}

echo"<pre>"; print_r($dd);
?>
```

OUTPUT :

> Array (
>       [1] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => banana
>               [1] => apple
>               [2] => raspberry
>           )
>
> ```
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => apple
>         [1] => raspberry
>     )
>
> [a] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => raspberry
>     )
>
> [0] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => orange
>         [1] => banana
>         [2] => apple
>         [3] => raspberry
>     )
> ```
>
> )

Comment: `$dd` is not defined prior to the for loop, this will result in errors.

Comment: Bro this is tested working fine... Please check code ?

Comment: "Working" does not mean it is error free. Undefined variables being used will throw notices, which are errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to get the value of the first element in the array (without removing it), use `reset($stack)`.

`array_shift()` will remove the element from the array and return the value.

Comment: He said without reseting

Comment: There's no way to get the "first" key without resetting, so that means he's asking for something that cannot be done. Not to mention the question is worded poorly.

Comment: Actually if I use reset function it reset all keys and set it from zero.. I would not want this...

Comment: `reset` does not empty an array, it merely resets the internal pointer to the first element in the array. A `foreach` loop does the same thing before it executes.